# If I proved that f(x) is uniformly continouos on any closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$, can i say it's continouos on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

It seems intuitive. For example,  $x^n$. I can easily show that $x^n$ is uniformly continouos on any interval $[a,b]$ using induction:

$$|x^n-c^n|=|x-c||x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}c+...c^{n-1}|<\delta |x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}c+...c^{n-1}|$$

since $x^{n-1}, x^{n-2}...$ etc are continuous, $|x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}c+...c^{n-1}|$ attain a maximum M at the closed interval $[a,b]$, so:

$$|x^n-c^n|<\delta M < \epsilon$$
so $\delta<\epsilon / M$.

I proved it is uniformly continouos for any interval $[a,b]$, does this mean it is continuous on all $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: yes you can. For any point $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, consider any closed interval that contains $x_0$ I the interior, say $[x_0-1,x_0+1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $a\in\Bbb R$. You know that $f|_{[a-1,a+1]}$ is uniformly continuous. Therefore, $f|_{[a-1,a+1]}$ is continuous. So, $f$ is continuous at every point of $(a-1,a+1)$; in particular, it is continuous at $a$.